# non english (hebrew) chars in hostname

Tags: internationalization, dns, hebrew, hostname

Is it official? Where is it defined?

How can I transform between the english and non-english version, programmatically?

I see domains that google recognizes as hebrew, but the browser does not.

Examples:

http://www.xn----ogc3ffxd2br0d.com/
http://www.xn------wpehbcibg3bcah2ftaym6h.com/
http://www.xn----6hcesc7ap3c.ws/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name#ToASCII_and_ToUnicode

Answer (score 2):

This is PUNYCODE with ACE prefix. The most popular library to handle this is

http://www.gnu.org/software/libidn/

Answer (score 1):

Official, yes, it is [IDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name) (Internationalized Domain Names) and it is defined (since 2003) in [RFC 3490](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3490.txt). (Although ".il" does not seem to allow them...)

There are several free software libraries to handle it:

- [GNU libidn](http://www.gnu.org/software/libidn/)
- [Verisign SDK](http://www.verisign.com/domain-name-services/current-registrars/internationalized-domain-names/index.html)
- [JP NIC mDNkit/idnkit](http://www.nic.ad.jp/ja/idn/mdnkit/download/documents/mdnkit-2.4-doc/en/index.html)